# Are the problems in Google with including keywords in addition the brand name in the domain name?

Tags: seo, google, domains

I have a client and he do logo design. Still he is not registered the company too. He is targeting keywords like "logo design", etc.

He can register company name as "Cretvoit Pvt Ltd" or "Cretvoit Logo Design Pvt Ltd". Then domain would be `cretvoit.in` or `cretvoitlogodesign.in`.

That second domain is similar to extract match domains, Right?  Are there any problem using second domain because Google hates exact match domains?

Comment: That isn't "exact match domains".    An EMD wouldn't have the brand name in it at all.   It would just have the popular keywords that people search for: "logodesign.tld".

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks. How about pro as prefix.... I have another client who need to register the domain prowebdesign.tld. His company will be Pro Web Design Pvt Ltd. Will it consider as EMD?

Comment: If it doesn't exactly match, it isn't "exact match".   You still have legit questions about including keywords with the domain though, I'm not sure that is a good idea even without exact matches these days.